# Are there any single chip solutions for single cell LiPo battery protection? If not, any references?

Tags: lipo, current-limiting, undervoltage

I can't seem to find one, but does anyone know of a single chip solution for LiPo battery protection on a single cell/3.7V battery? Looking for things like over-current/overvoltage/undervoltage protection. I wan't to be able to either have redundant protection or be able to use wholesale LiPos without protection to add some safety.

If not, does anyone know of a reference on how to design one? I'm more interested in learning how to design a circuit as opposed to a single chip solution since they are usually cheaper, but can't find any blog posts/papers/lessons/etc.

Comment: How many discrete components are you willing to allow?

Comment: I think this question falls on the right side of the EE.SE scope and should not be closed. OP is looking for a recommendations on a type of IC, or ways to design if not available.

Comment: A handful of discretes are fine (such as an external mosfet, etc)

Comment: If the OP has found any solutions that aren't among those recommended, please post. I have a similar situation. My project already incorporates a MAX1555 IC for charging a single LiPO cell, and previously only had a warning to alert the user of Low battery. Now i wish I had incorporated an automated complete shutdown. In my case, my entire circuit only consumes 10mA, so I'm hopeful I can find a one chip  under-voltage shutdown that might not even need an external FET. I'm considering "cajoling" an MCP111 to the task, but I'm skeptical it wouldn't need a FET too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TI have some e.g. http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/bq77908adbt/battery-protector-li-ion-lipol/dp/2323730 although that one's not particularly cheap.

Ricoh: http://www.ricoh.com/LSI/product_power/bmu/

You can also get protection PCBs as a product.

Comment: The links have gone dead by now. Could anyone replace them with actual part numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Atmel has a small selection of [battery-oriented AVRs](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/battery_management.aspx) that provide overcurrent, overvoltage, and undervoltage protection, as well as a high-voltage I/O/interrupt pin and 3V3 SPI communication.

The reference circuit design for the Atmega8HVA/16HVA uses 2 MOSFETs, 12 resistors, and 8 capacitors to manage 1 cell, but in exchange for all those discretes you get a MCU that knows almost everything about the cell connected to it.